# Show that every map of $S^{k + l} \rightarrow S^k \times S^l$ induces the given trivial homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Here is the question:

> [image]

Could anyone give me a hint on how to do so please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: first use the cup product structure to determine that $f^*$ is trivial. Then use naturality of the short exact sequence
$$0\to \operatorname{Ext}(H_{k+\ell-1}(X),\Bbb Z)\to H^{k+\ell}(X)\to \operatorname{Hom}(H_{k+\ell}(X),\Bbb Z)\to 0$$
to get the result.

As to the second part, there must be a typo because there are no such maps $S^2\to S^1\times S^1$ (since $\pi_2(S^1\times S^1)=0$).

Comment: Could you provide some details about why there ia a typo in the second part. Like how did you calculate the second homotopy group of the torus and why when it is zero there are no such maps ?

Comment: Also could you provide more details about using the cup product structure to show that $f^*$ is trivial please?

Comment: It turns out that $S^1$ only has one nontrivial homotopy group, and in general $\pi_n(X\times Y)=\pi_n(X)\times \pi_n(Y)$ (at least if things are countable generated or something). So $\pi_2(S^1\times S^1)=\pi_2(S^1)\times \pi_2(S^1)=0$. The group $\pi_2(S^1\times S^1)$ is exactly the homotopy classes of maps $S^2\to S^1\times S^1$ (which fix a base point, although that doesn’t matter here). An element of $[f]\in \pi_n(X)$ is a class of maps, and $f$ is null homotopy if and only if $[f]=0$.

Comment: Also I think the second part said there exists not for all …. am I correct?

Comment: like in the second part we can take different $k,l$ am I correct?

Comment: I think I am correct ….. but how to prove the existence then?

Comment: It's ambiguous whether the second statement means "$\forall k,l >0 \text{ there are essential maps }S^{k+l} \to S^k \times S^l$" or if it means "$\exists k,l >0 \text{ such that there are essential maps }S^{k+l} \to S^k \times S^l$". If it means "$\forall\dots$" then Elliot G is correct that it's not true as stated, since there is no essential map $S^2 \to S^1 \times S^1$. If it means "$\exists \dots$" then an example is $k=1,\ l=2$ since $\pi_3(S^1\times S^2)\cong \pi_3(S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ (because of the Hopf fibration).